# In which position should "that" go?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, optional-that

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> A. An oven that clean itself is very handy.

> > B. An oven clean itself that is very handy.

If there is any wrong sentence, then explain it with some examples.

Comment: @Lambie I read that as "if either sentence is wrong..."

Comment: @Lambie Yes, it's definitely wrong as written. I just guessed at a slightly different meaning.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not really disagreeing with you here; I'm saying "yes, I agree, that sentence is incorrect; since it's not clear, I wonder if you have guessed the meaning right, or if I did". Both meanings are, basically, saying the same thing, I just thought I'd mention what my guess was.

Comment: There are many ways to help. If you had another rewrite, just put it up. When  an OP's English is this level, and refuses to interact, there is no more one can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are *grammatically* correct with one adjustment but mean slightly different things.

Firstly, since there is only one "oven", you need the singular form of "clean", which is "cleans".

> An oven that cleans itself is very handy.

This would mean that there is an oven which cleans itself, and the speaker is commenting that it is handy (useful).

The phrase "that cleans itself" is said to "qualify" oven - it's not just any oven, it's *an oven that cleans itself*. That entire phrase then acts as the subject of the phrase "is very handy".

> An oven cleans itself that is very handy.

This would be a slightly awkward but acceptable way to say "an oven that is very handy cleans itself".

In this case, "... that is very handy" qualifies "oven", and "an oven that is very handy" becomes the subject of "cleans itself". So the usefulness is already known, and the self-cleaning is new information.

*This sentence is grammatically correct, but probably not what you wanted to say.*

You can change the word order of the original *without* changing the meaning, but the result sounds awkward because key facts are left to the end:

> An oven is very handy that cleans itself.

We might use this ability to vary word order for emphasis, e.g.:

> An oven is on special offer that cleans itself.

places greater emphasis on the "special offer" than:

> An oven that cleans itself is on special offer.

---

As an additional point, the use of "is" implies that there is a real self-cleaning oven you're referring to. If you are wishing one existed, or wishing you had one, you would need to use "would be" instead of "is".

Comment: "Is" could also be used if speaking in the abstract -- whether a person in general would find it very handy, rather than a particular person.

Comment: @Mary I guess I didn't word that part very well: my point was that "is" requires the oven to exist somewhere, whereas "would be" can be used for talking about a hypothetical or imaginary oven.

Comment: The OP fixed the misspelling on the same day the question was posted. The merit is all yours, the OP will probably never misspell oven ever again. But your answer appears confusing because it continues to mention "woven"; you could get rid of those references and still have a half-decent answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for pointing that out; I've deleted that part of the answer, and expanded the rest.

Answer (score 1):

**- A self-cleaning oven is very convenient.**

Some appliances may handy (if small) but a self-cleaning oven refers to an oven that is using a process, so it can't be said to be handy. The self-cleaning feature can be easy or convenient to use.

That is simply the way this is said.

An oven **that** clean**s** itself is self-cleaning.

[third person: An oven that cleans itself requires an s on the verb.]

Read all about them in How Stuff Works

[Self-cleaning oven](https://home.howstuffworks.com/self-cleaning-ovens2.htm)

The word ***that*** introducing a clause generally follows the word to which it refers.

**The car that is in the garage** is very old.

Comment: +1 if you explain why the OP's B sentence is ungrammatical. `An oven clean itself that is very handy.`

Comment: Why isn't a self-cleaning oven "handy"? Isn't it useful?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I explained why I thought it wasn't.  A cleaning process is not handy, a thing is. Also, I did explain why it was wrong as I wrote: An oven that cleans itself is self-cleaning, with the s in bold. A cleaning process can be convenient.

Comment: A machine is handy, a process is easy or convenient.

Comment: **A self-cleaning oven is designed to stay locked until the high temperature process is completed**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-cleaning_oven#:~:text=A%20self%2Dcleaning%20oven%20is%20designed%20to%20stay%20locked%20until,to%20prevent%20possible%20burn%20injuries.

Comment: **The biggest appeal of self-cleaning ovens is their convenience. You don't have to scrape and scrub to remove spilled food, and the oven can be running through a cleaning cycle while you spend time on other chores or simply relax.** https://homeguides.sfgate.com/pros-cons-selfcleaning-ovens-69125.html#:~:text=Convenience,other%20chores%20or%20simply%20relax.

Comment: @Mar-LouA See what I mean re the comment I made to you in chat? Two downvotes, my,my.

Comment: @IMSoP There is nothing like trying to destroy something that makes great sense. self-cleaning is a process. Do you really want to be associated with saying that it isn't?? Your answer was chosen so what are you complaining about? Sour grapes?

Comment: @IMSoPUnbelievable, Of course, **it is grammatical to say "an oven that cleans itself";** a "self-cleaning oven" **just takes it to the next terminology level**. That is something the OP can now **use**. I just spoke this very minute to a house builder doing work in my living room and asked him" Is a self-cleaning oven convenient or handy? He said convenient.

Comment: @IMSoP Whatever, I am fed up with this. Let the OP chose your answer. He or she is clearly not interested. You keep dragging this out in a ridiculous manner when clearly my answer is just much better than yours regardless of how one looks at it.

Comment: @Lambie I have removed my downvote, and deleted my comments. While I still don't agree with the opinion you state in the answer regarding when "handy" may be used, you have at least stated it clearly now.

Comment: @IMSoP Like I said, machines are not usually said to be handy. A hand-held appliance may be handy, even a toaster oven is handy because you can use it instead of having to light a regular oven. Something that is handy is usually something that involves interactions with the object. But not just turning on an oven so it self-cleans.

Comment: @Lambie You've got me thinking about whether I can define any rules for where I'd use "handy". :) "Within reach" is presumably the etymology, but etymology is not always a good guide to current usage.  I hear it quite often used to describe fairly _abstract_ things, e.g. flowcharts, mnemonics; so if the phrase in question was "a handy self-cleaning feature", that would sound fine to my ear. I admit something _really large_ like "a handy caravan" sounds odd; but "a handy cupboard" seems to be fine (and quite common). On the other hand, the related "the caravan came in handy" sounds fine.

Comment: @IMSoP Of course, a handy cupboard is fine because it means within reach for the purpose of storing things. A handy flowchart is that way because it is also usable as a physical object.  An online flowchart is not handy. Mnemonics can be handy in the sense of easy to use. For me handy is the "antonym" of unwieldy....:)

Comment: @Lambie I'm not sure "easy to use" is quite the right definition; it needs an element of "helpful" or "useful" in there. It's definitely not natural _everywhere_ that "useful" or "convenient" would be, but I'm still not quite convinced that there's a clear line that "self-cleaning oven" would fall on the wrong side of. There's also slightly different usages, like "my new house is handy for the station", where it means something more like "within reach of". I guess people find it a handy word to use in lots of different situations. ;)